# "Запаковать" локальный хост для запуска на другой машине

Tags: apache, linux

**Здравствуйте!**

Ситуация такая, на компьютере (ос `Ubuntu Linux`) есть настроенный локальный хост, на котором создавался сайт.

Сейчас нужно чтобы точно также локально этот сайт работал на любой другой машине, знаю, что это делают при использовании denwer'a (видел файлы сайта, апача и т.д. запакованные в .rar архив), а как проделать такое в моем случае?

Answer (score 4):

Не согласен с [[@rvs](/users/1665/rvs)](/users/1665/rvs) )) не нужно исходить из того, что задачу решить невозможно или сложно, я исхожу из того, что она простая, либо типичная, а затем усложняем индивидуально для текущей.

Сайт перенести можно, если сайт, это файлы ***/var/www/site*** и база ***mysql sitedb***  или ***mysql -p sitedb*** (она же */var/lib/mysql/sitedb*), то бэкап файлов делается с помошью

```
google howto backup tar gz
```

бэкап базы делается так

```
google howto backup mysqldump
```

конфигурация apache в /etc/apache2/... "в любой другой системе", если имеется ввиду linux она может находиться в /etc/httpd/...

восстановление из бэкапов описано в тех же хауту

Answer (score 1):

В общем случае - никак, так как на другой машине может быть другая ОС (другие версии apache/php и библиотек) да и вообще другая архитектура. Обычно просто пакуют фалйы проекта и дают инструкцию по установке с примерами конфигурационных файлов апача.

Если уж очень сильно хочется то можно попробовать взять что-нибудь типа Facebook'овского php компилятора (если речь о php?) и сделать большой статичный бинарник который должен без проблем запускаться на любой машине такой же архитектуры. Правда это будет не апач а что-то другое.

Comment: Эх, судя по всему слишком "энергозатратно" получается. А речь о Perl-скриптах. Спасибо за ответ.

Comment: Чтобы юзать perl-script, надо сперва Perl поставить!

Answer (score 1):

У вас это единичный случай или Вы хотите сделать такую систему архивации с последующим переносом на другую машину?

Если единичный случай,пакуйте в ручную, заархивируйте в один файл все файлы и папки(сохранив структуру) и дам базы данных.

Дамп базы из под линукс:

```
mysqldump -u root -p -f mydatabase > /home/myname/mydatabasedump.sql
```

Или, если есть `phpmyadmin`, то им можно.

Далее разворачиваете все на другой машине, заведомо создав там БД и настроив `apache`. Эту процедуру можно автоматизировать с помощью `php` (нужны права доступа) или `perl`.

Answer (score -1):

В Денвере (если вы это имеете в виду: http://www.denwer.ru/), локальный хост может быть без ущерба, но с ограничениями, спокойно перенесён под него! Вам надо всего лишь поставить Denwer, а потом скопировать, и прописать там свой сайт. Работает с флешки, как и обещано. НО - только PHP+MySQL, и ничего более! И никогда и нигде - абсолютных ссылок!!!

Comment: всё как раз наоборот